# WPF effect - проблемы с перерисовкой окна

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

В проекте использую C# и WPF, Net.Framework 4.7
Столкнулся с проблемой, что перерисовка окна с наложением эффекта происходит только после завершения функции, а пока она не закрылась эффект, наложенный на окно, не отображается. Причем это включает в себя и вложенные функции. Пример моего кода:

```
private void ButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();

        System.Windows.Media.Effects.BlurEffect objBlur = new System.Windows.Media.Effects.BlurEffect();
        objBlur.Radius = 4;
        this.Effect = objBlur;

        UpdateList();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);//в исходном коде этой строчки нет, добавлено для личной наглядности
        this.Effect = null;
    }
```

Ожидание вставил, чтобы убедится, что до завершения ничего не происходит. В UpdateList у меня обновление данных из сетевого файла excel - пользователю в это время показывается прогресс бар, но вот замылить окно ввода не получается, приложение упорно ждет завершения всех вложенных действий, закрытий метода по клику и только после этого перерисовывает (скорее всего даже дважды) окно.
Надеюсь мне подскажут что у меня не так.

Comment: `private async void ButtonUpdate_Click(...){ ... await Task.Delay(2000); вместо Thread.Sleep(2000);.....}`

Comment: Во первых, в WPF принято использовать XAML для стилей, эффектов и прочего. Используя в коде то, что у вас - вы сами себе вставляете палки  колеса, да и теряете много вкусного и удобного. Во вторых, весь интерфейс обрабатывается в одном потоке и написав очень долгую логику/паузу потока (`Thread.Sleep()`), вы блокируете полностью весь UI поток, он попросту ждет. Для того, что бы такого не было, "долгую логику" стоит обернуть в async/await (комментарий выше), либо вовсе вынести в отдельный поток.

Comment: Thread.Sleep(2000); я вставил лишь для того чтобы убедится, что перерисовка не происходит вовремя, по изначальной логике программы специально задержки нет.
в оригинале у меня так
private void ButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();

        System.Windows.Media.Effects.BlurEffect objBlur = new System.Windows.Media.Effects.BlurEffect();
        objBlur.Radius = 4;
        this.Effect = objBlur;

        UpdateList();
        this.Effect = null;
    }
Должна быть перерисовка до UpdateList и обратно после него.

Comment: Сути не меняется. Полагаю, что в `UpdateList()` у вас всё так же синхронно и выполняется в UI потоке, поэтому, как уже сказали: "долгую логику" стоит обернуть в async/await (комментарий выше), либо вовсе вынести в отдельный поток.

Comment: Долгая логика, в моем случае - это обработка здоровенного excel-ского файла (причем там открыть его приходится через excel из-за строенных формул, и не спрашивайте меня почему так, оно так ибо общая архитектура  системы не мной проектировалась). Сейчас при включении этой процедуры я увожу активность с окна в диалоговое окно (правда в другом потоке) в виде прогресс-бара без возможности закрытия, и не вижу необходимости делать отдельный поток для обработки, так как пока она не закончится делать что-либо в окне приложения бессмысленно, ну разве что иметь возможность закрыть его.